# Retrieving values for Selectize.js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am using [Selectize.js](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) to create a tagging like experience, for adding users to jobs, using the current users of the system.

**In my view**

Following the documentation, I have a select box with the **multiple** attribute which I populate with the users on the system. I have also declared that this input is an array by adding square braces.

```
<select name="job_administrator[]" multiple id="selectize" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('job_administrator') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}">
    <option value="">Select a user </option>
    @foreach($users as $user)
    <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->full_name }} - {{ $user->access_level }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Then, I initialize the plugin

```
$('#selectize').selectize({
    placeholder: 'Select user',
    plugins: ['remove_button'],
    delimiter: ',',
    persist: false,
})
```

**In my Controller**

```
/**
 * Handle adding job administrators to jobs
 *
 * @param Array $data
 * @return void
 */
public function addAdministrators(Array $data, int $id)
{
    $vacancy = JobPost::where('id', $id)->first();

    if(!empty($data['job_administrator'])){
        $jobAdmins = $data['job_administrator'];

        // Grab the IDs for the tags in the array
        $admins = Admin::whereIn('id', $jobAdmins)->get()->pluck('id');

        $vacancy->administrators()->sync($admins);
    } else {
        // If there were no tags, remove them from this model instance
        $vacancy->administrators()->sync(array());
    }

}
```

My question is: on the editing screen is it possible to prefill the selected items when using Selectize?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, just add the selected attribute to the option. You can do something like this.

```
<option value="{{ $user->id }}" {{$selected->contains($user->id) ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{ $user->full_name }} - {{ $user->access_level }}</option>
```

The $selected is then a collection of ids.